# The probability of the student passing in test A,B,C are p,q and 1/2.If the probability that the student successful is 1/2.Then?

Tags: probability

> A student appears for tests A,B and C.
>
> The student is successful if he passes either in tests A and test B or tests A and test C.
>
> The probability of the student passing in test A,B,C are p,q and 1/2.If the probability that the student successful is 1/2.Then,

options are:

1 p=1,q=0

2 p=0,q=1

3 p/q=1

4 infinitely many solutions

My Approach:

E:Event that student is successful in test A

F:Event that he is successful in test B

G:E:Event that he is successful in test C

@Edit
p(he is successfull)=p(E)*p(F)*p(not G)+p(E)*p(not F)*p(G)+p(E)*p(F)*p(G)

=p*q*(1-1/2)+p*(1-q)*1/2+p*q*1/2=(pq+p-pq+pq)/2=p(1+q)/2

p(1+q)/2=1/2

(because given that probability of student that he is successful is 1/2)

From here i get p=1,q=0.

> I am stuck from here.How to solve other options from here.

Comment: By "the probability that the student successful", you mean the probability of passing tests A, B and C?

Comment: The probability he's successful appears to be 
$$P(E)P(F)P(\overline G) + P(E)P(\overline F)P(G) + P(E)P(F)P(G).$$ You have something a bit different.

Comment: @GBQT "Student is successful if he passes test A and test B or test A and Test C".

Comment: Is there a secret assumption that passing the different tests are independent events? That wouldn't sound very realistic, but without it you can't conclude anything (except that $p$ must be at least $1/2$).

Comment: @Henning Makholm No secret assumption it is just that he has to clear test A and test B or test A and  test C in order to be successful.Also Test A has no dependence on Test B so i took them as independence events and similarly for other.

Comment: What do you mean by "Test A has no dependence on Test B", if not a secret assumption that passing test A and passing test B are independent events? Note that no such assumption is stated in the problem description, and in practice it would be ridiculously unlikely that there's not _some_ sort of correlation between test results that are sufficiently topically related that they are combined to find overall success for a student.

Comment: @CarlHeckman: Your formula depends on assuming that $E$, $F$ and $G$ are independent events. That assumption is both highly unrealistic and not supported by the OP's problem description.

Comment: @Henning Makholm No such assumption is given in the problem and i thought it would work like this because i think thought test A passing marks would have no dependence on second.Suggestions are welcome if that is not the case.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm: I don't see how to solve the problem if the events ARE dependent. Not enough data is given in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Without an explicit assumption that passing the three tests are statistically independent events, I don't think you can conclude anything except:

- $p\ge \frac12$, otherwise test A alone will force too many students to fail.
- $(1-p)+(1-\max(q,\frac12))\ge\frac12$, otherwise too *few* students can fail. This simplifies to $p+q\le \frac32$.

---

Even if you do assume independence, neither of your options 1, 2, or 3 can be right, because $(p,q)=(\frac12,1)$ is certainly a possibility both with and without independence.

Another possibility where the tests are independent would be $(p,q)=(\frac23,\frac12)$.

Comment: Not understood your equation (p,1)=(1/2,1)

Comment: @justintakro: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be $(p,q)=(\frac12,1)$.

Comment: Independence events (p,q)= (2/3,1/2)?Ans given is d infinite many solutions.